# Не могу открыть XML файл из сети

Tags: python, lxml

Нужно достать определенные объекты из XML файла, но не могу понять как его открыть.

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

root = etree.fromstring(requests.get('https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=2').text)
for appt in root.getchildren():
        for elem in appt.getchildren():
            if not elem.text:
                text = "None"
            else:
                text = elem.text

            print(elem.tag + " => " + text)
```

Вывод:

```
(VIRTUAL_ENV) Milkiweeds-MacBook-Pro:Desktop milkiweed$ python q.py 
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
query => None
```

Comment: Какой результат нужен-то? Внутри элементов `<query/>` на самом деле нет никакого текста, что ожидается-то?

Comment: @andreymal https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=2. Отсюда вытащить некоторые цифры. Как это реализовать можно?(

Comment: Все цифры в атрибутах, к атрибутам и обращайтесь, `elem.get('amountin')` и всё такое

Comment: @andreymal спасибо огромное!